# What are those nul bytes doing in Certificate Subject CN?

Tags: tls, certificates

While doing some research with SSL certificates, I found some weird certificates containing nul bytes in their Subject field. One example is `www.refah - bank.ir` (did the Iranian government fake this CA? It looks very similar to a Spanish CA except for location...).

Another example is `mcafee.com` which looks more trustworthy to me. They have two different IP addresses for `mcafee.com` and `www.mcafee.com`, the certificate also differs. What surprised me was that such a company uses certificates containing nul bytes in their Subject field:

```
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number:
        c8:e6:3c:67:a8:7f:38:ba:c9:ab:06:ef:4e:68:67:0d
Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: O=Network Associates, OU=NAI Certificate Services, CN=NAI SSL CA v1
    Validity
        Not Before: Aug 26 20:36:38 2008 GMT
        Not After : Apr 26 09:28:50 2019 GMT
    Subject: C=US, ST=Texas, L=Plano, O=McAfee, Inc, OU=IIS-Plano, CN=\x00*\x00.\x00m\x00c\x00a\x00f\x00e\x00e\x00.\x00c\x00o\x00m
```

Opening `mcafee.com` correctly rejected the certificate as the wildcard does not match against this. Out of curiosity, I edited my host file and made `foo.mcafee.com` (and `www.`) point to the IP address 161.69.13.40 (mcafee.com).
I would expect such a certificate to be rejected, but Firefox and Chromium both accept this certificate.

I found another website that has nul bytes in the CN and is still "trusted": https://www.digiturk.com.tr

What is happening here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a badly encoded Common Name. The Common Name, like many elements of a Distinguished Name, can be encoded in several ways, including `UTF8String` (that's UTF-8) and `BMPString`. The latter is more or less the same as UTF-16, with two bytes per character (except surrogates, which I won't talk about here). Apparently, someone encoded `*.mcafee.com` in big-endian UTF-16, but it was decoded as if it was UTF-8 (or ASCII), leading to the spurious null bytes. It was probably improperly tagged in the certificate.

Comment: Thank you, I also found your [other extensive answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5142550/427545) describing the allowed characters in a CN. Point 6 in [this mailing list message](http://www.mail-archive.com/cryptography@randombit.net/msg03267.html) is probably the cause of having a weird CN here.

Comment: Using http://lapo.it/asn1js/, I was able to determine that the CN is indeed a BMPString and that openssl is broken here in the sense that it cannot decode it properly. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, `openssl` is probably dumping the "raw" bytes. When I use `openssl x509 -nameopt sep_comma_plus_space`, the value gets decoded to a human-readable string.